# FeathersJS + VueJS + Kerberos: how to?

Tags: vue.js, kerberos, feathersjs

In a webapp, I'm using FeathersJS (on localhost:3000) as backend and VueJS as frontend (on localhost:8080), with a feathers-vuex connection.

I have to implement a Kerberos SPNEGO authentication, and I'm using the "kerberos" npm package on an Express Middleware for this (so on Feathers side), but I have no idea what I have to do for binding informations retrieved from the kerberos ticket on the Vue side.
For example, when I call Feathers services directly on my browser on localhost:3000/, I can log kerberos informations on the Express middleware, but here my understanding stop :(.

Have I to use some kerberos API on Vue side ?
Can I manage the problem only with a custom feathers authentication ?
What I don't understand is how will feathers know the use of kerberos, if I only request on Vue side ? Because the browser get the kerberos ticket only if the server respond "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate" on the headers.

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: Good luck. Kerberos auth via the web is a pain.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm in a similar position, trying to access TIBCO DV protected by kerberos from a NodeJS API with a VueJS Client.